# What is the $condition input parameter for in a GraphQL mutation generated by AWS Amplify CLI?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, graphql-mutation, graphql-codegen

I have generated a simple GraphQL API on AWS AppSync (using CLI) from this model:

```
type WalletProperty @model {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
}
```

This generated a CreateWalletProperty, UpdateWalletProperty and DeleteWalletProperty mutations all similar to this:

```
  mutation CreateWalletProperty(
    $input: CreateWalletPropertyInput!
    $condition: ModelWalletPropertyConditionInput    <<<<<<<<<<<<  what is this for?
  ) {
    createWalletProperty(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      title
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
```

and the schema for the condition being:

```
input ModelWalletPropertyConditionInput {
  title: ModelStringInput
  and: [ModelWalletPropertyConditionInput]
  or: [ModelWalletPropertyConditionInput]
  not: ModelWalletPropertyConditionInput
}
```

Given that I always have to supply the mandatory $input, what is the $condition parameter for?

Comment: not marked wit `!` then not mandatory/not required ... optional parameter to filter affected rows/items

Comment: @xadm, thanks. I've just tested it and it appears it gets applied together with the input parameter. Given the $input is already mandatory I cannot think of a use-case where this actually makes sense or could be applied?

Comment: for create not, but for update ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case above the GraphQL is backed by a DynamoDB table;

Behind the scenes, the GraphQL operations translate to PutItem, UpdateItem, and DeleteItem DynamoDB operations.

For these data manipulation operations, DynamoDB API allows you to specify a condition expression to determine which items should be modified. If the condition expression evaluates to true, the operation succeeds; otherwise, the operation fails.

You can read more about use cases for each of these conditions on the AWS [Condition Expressions DynamoDB dev guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)

At GraphQL mutation level, only if the record meets the condition, will the mutation go ahead. Otherwise the mutation is not allowed and a ConditionalCheckFailedException is returned:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "deleteWalletProperty"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "DynamoDB:ConditionalCheckFailedException",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 12,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: E3PR9OM6M5J1QBHKNT8E4SM1DJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)"
    }
  ]
```